# Does Far Cry 3 automatically adjust difficulty level?

Tags: far-cry-3

I noticed few times, after multiple failures, that some enemies are not spawned in a places of my death. Example: after jump from a plane, you land on a beach and have to kill group of pirates and take their truck. I failed few times and, after that, pirates have not been spawned, so I could just walk in and take the car. Is that a bug or is there any mechanism that automatically adjust game difficulty in case when player struggles somewhere? If such mechanism exists, is there a way to disable it? I am playing on Windows 10, maximum difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that this is a function existing in-game. It could possibly be a result of constantly reloading the level, causing the privateers to not spawn correctly. So most likely a bug.